# Dead keys not working in Java Swing applications

Tags: keyboard, java, locale

I'm currently using Ubuntu 10.10 and Netbeans 7.0 and I can't type accented letters with dead keys any more. It's not a version specific problem seems it's related with Swing since I've got the same problem with older version of Netbeans and OS.

When I type <kbd>'</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> on any app on Linux I get a `á` vowel. All Linux apps are working fine, but Netbeans doesn't. When I type <kbd>'</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> on Netbeans I get a `a` vowel (no accent). I can't type quotes and double quotes either.

But I got accents on Netbeans using the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. (that's not what I want)

At terminal I got the following locale:

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: That effect of `'+` would be an [input method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method). Input methods are processed by each application, so whether they work depends on what libraries the application uses. I don't know what input method uses `'+` or whether Netbeans can be made to use it.

Comment: I'm not typing the plus "+" key..... I tried to explain the keystrokes eg: "'" + "a" = "á" understand it now?

Comment: Ah, I get it. It wasn't clear at all in your original post, lacking both the formatting (kind of hard to find in the documentation, I admit) and the standard terminology “dead keys”.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've just found the fix for the same problem, thanks to [this answer](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5485348;jsessionid=AC90E67E77944B70A337D368B22A788A#5485348).

Briefly: seems to be a problem with ibus. I've tried both to launch the java app (in my case `freemind`) with `XMODIFIERS="" freemind` and setting up ibus with `ibus-setup` and now I can write accented vowels (using deadkeys in the ES keyboard).